# async fn calling split generates error "borrowed value does not live long enough"

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I've created a contrived example to understand an error I'm seeing with an async function using tokio:

```
pub async fn unique_words_async() -> io::Result<u32> {
    let file = File::open("sample.txt").await?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let mut lines = reader.lines();

    let mut h = HashMap::new();
    h.insert("word", true);
    while let Some(line) = lines.next_line().await? {
        let mut split = line.trim().split(' ');
        while let Some(word) = split.next() {
            h.insert(word, true);
        }
    }
    Ok(h.len() as u32)
}
```

here's the exact error:

```
16 |         let mut split = line.trim().split(' ');
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
20 |     }
   |     - `line` dropped here while still borrowed
21 |     Ok(h.len() as u32)
   |        ------- borrow later used here
```

see running live in [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=68082a46d28df4486dcfb9e93f4860cf)

The non-async code to accomplish the same task works fine (see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c94987e47fb74864d1dbfd5adf9a2a83)):

```
pub fn unique_words() -> u32 {
    let input = "this is one line\nhere is another line";
    let mut lines = input.lines();
    let mut h = std::collections::HashMap::new();
    while let Some(line) = lines.next() {
        let mut split = line.split(' ');
        while let Some(word) = split.next() {
            h.insert(word, true);
        }
    }
    h.len() as u32
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your non-async translation is incorrect. If you will use `File` with `BufReader`, you will have the same error:

```rust
pub fn unique_words() -> std::io::Result<u32> {
    use std::io::BufRead;

    let file = std::fs::File::open("sample.txt")?;
    let reader = std::io::BufReader::new(file);
    let mut lines = reader.lines();

    let mut h = std::collections::HashMap::new();
    while let Some(line) = lines.next().transpose()? {
        let mut split = line.split(' ');
        while let Some(word) = split.next() {
            h.insert(word, true);
        }
    }
    Ok(h.len() as u32)
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `line` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:25
   |
10 |         let mut split = line.split(' ');
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
14 |     }
   |     - `line` dropped here while still borrowed
15 |     Ok(h.len() as u32)
   |        ------- borrow later used here
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c001a8789b9697156e79c39463082f5f).

This is because [`Lines::next()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Lines.html#method.next) returns `Option<io::Result<String>>`, and the `String` is dropped at the end of each loop turn. However, [`str::trim()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) and [`str::split()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.split) takes `&str` and produce `&str` with the same lifetime (as they only slice the string, not change it). Thus you push into `h` a `&str` with the lifetime of one loop turn, that is, a dangling reference.

The reason it worked with [`str::lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines) is that [`std::str::Lines::next()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/struct.Lines.html#method.next) returns `Option<&str>` with the reference tied to the original `&str`, which is `'static`.

The simplest way to fix that is to convert the `&str` to an owned `String`:

```rust
h.insert(word.to_owned(), true);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6c29e052d15ac5eb177d027bedd249b7).